# Lost in a simple MVC case - how do I return multiple Users?

Tags: model-view-controller, oop, architecture

I'm not sure which title would be more descriptive, so I kept it this way. I feel kinda lost in the world of MVC.

FYI: I use PHP, but that doesn't seem of much importance in this particular case.

My problem is as follows:

I have a UserController containing the following methods:

- login
- new
- show
- overview

Then I have my UserModel, containing - in this case - roughly the same methods:

- login
- create
- fetch

The problem is: what do I keep my user data in once fetched from the database (or XML feed, or webservice, or whatever...)? I thought of a User 'business object', containing all (relevant) properties from the database. Then, when fetching the users from the database, I instantiate a new User object for each user I fetch. If only 1 user returned from the search, I return only the User object. If more users get returned, I instantiate a UserCollection object containing all User objects - in which case I can iterate over them, etcetera.

Is that a correct way of dealing with users in MVC?

And then: imagine I made an overview of 10 users. 5 of them get edited at once - imagine a status modification using checkboxes. How do I process the changes? Do I loop over all changed User objects and store them back in the database? Then it would start to look like an implementation of the Active Record Pattern, something I'm told not to use.

I hope someone can clarify which classes and/or methods I'd need to solve this 'architectural' problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, your UserModel is a bit off;
the Model part of MVC is intended as a programmatic representation of the real world model.
Meaning- it represents all the *properties* and *actions* of the real-world subject. The classic example is the `Car` class, which has properties such as `Wheel`, `CurrentSpeed`, and actions such as `GoForward()`, `GoReverse()` etc..

So, in your case, I think your model should be what you described as a 'user business object'.
Your controller would be responsible for fetching the `UserModel`s from storage (or wherever), and updating them back.

your workflow would be something like this:
`View` would call the `Controller`'s `GetUsers`.
`Controller` goes to storage, and fetches a list of `UserModel`s.
`Controller` returns them to the view.
`View` displays them in some way.

And the other way around for updating.
The `UserModel` class would be responsible for logic that pertains to individual users (for example- `ChangePassword()`).

Answer (score 0):

Since it is a rather lengthy discussion. I will give the link to an article that I have written on MVC, trying to explain it in simple terms. You may want to take a look at it.

[What is MVC pattern about?](http://www.nazar-merza.com/index.php/getting-started/73-what-is-mvc-pattern-about)